# How to load scripts first when needed with require.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

**Background**

I have a long list of models and views made with [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Introduction) - but not all users will open all views.
I use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to load JavaScripts files and templates.

**What I have now**

I have a router that knows about all views. Since the router know this, all views, models and templates are therefore loaded at startup - this also loads randomly visited views.

**Problem**

How can I use require.js to load the JavaScripts when needed? Not in the initial startup, but  when user first opens a view.

**UPDATE**
I can now get this working as commented in answer below.

In router I have a require per route:

```
require(["yourmodule"], function(MyModule){
    //...
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great guide for marrying Backbone.js and Require.js:

http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Comment: In your router, you load your views - will require.js then load the full module graph? A view has a collection, and a collection again requires a model and so on. What I would like to know if I can load the module, when I actually need it

Comment: Have you tried something like this in your router handler?  `require(["yourmodule"], populateYourView)`

Comment: @IntoTheVoid: Please note that the current version of jQuery, Underscore and the branch of Backbone include support for AMD so the integration with RequireJS is a lot simpler now. Have a look at **[updated example](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/modular-backbone-updated)** on backbonetutorial's github or check out a simple **[Backbone Project Template](https://github.com/dzejkej/modular-backbone)**.

Comment: @dzejkej, what do you mean, is it backbone having a amd support, or is it the tutorials that have amd? I have followed this tutorials before, and can't see anything new.

Comment: @IntoTheVoid There is a branch of Backbone.js that supports AMD, so you don't need to create any of those wrappers described in the tutorial. Just have a look at the *links* from my comments and you wil l see that almost nothing is required to integrate Backbone.js + Underscore and jQuery with RequireJS. You have it all there.

Comment: For anyone looking at a more in-depth example of backbone+require.js check out http://backboneboilerplate.com